# Define instance variable just for iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I want to define an instance variable, just for iOS 8 like this:

```
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
```

How can I do it compatible with iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

`UIVisualEffect` was introduced in iOS8. It is not available for iOS7. [There](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) are [other](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60968/ios-7-blur-effects-gpuimage) ways of doing blurs in iOS7, though.

Comment: Yes, I know but my question it's if there is anyway to define an instance variable just for iOS8 some kind of macro.